# What's wrong with my Javascript/jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I presume it'll be rather obvious...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

function textValidate(field) {
    $("field").blur(function(){
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\sàèìòùáéíóúäëïöüñãõåæøâêîôû-]+$/;
        if (f_name.value.length > 1 && f_name.value.match(alphaExp)) {
            document.getElementById(field+"_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(field+"_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/cross.png' class='mark'>";
        }
    });
}

textValidate(#f_name);
textValidate(#l_name);

});
</script>
```

EDIT: my HTML...

```
<p>First name</p>
<input type="text" id="f_name"> <span id="f_name_mark"></span>
<p>Last name</p>
<input type="text" id="l_name">  <span id="f_name_mark"></span>
```

My intention is for the `<span>` to be populated by the cross or tick accordingly. At the moment I am getting no change, although I had this working when it was not a function and just straight-forward code applied to `#f_name`, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f_name").blur(function(){
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\sàèìòùáéíóúäëïöüñãõåæøâêîôû-]+$/;
        if (f_name.value.length > 1 && f_name.value.match(alphaExp)) {
            document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("f_name_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/cross.png' class='mark'>";
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do *you* think is wrong?

Comment: Why not `$(field + "_mark").html` if you are using jQuery? field is not a variable? The code by itself makes no sense.

Comment: Why do you mix pure JavaScript with jQuery when you already have jQuery included (somewhere before the code you gave I presume)? Also what do you mean "whats wrong". What is happening and what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 4):

```
textValidate(#f_name);
textValidate(#l_name);
```

should be

```
textValidate("#f_name");
textValidate("#l_name");
```

and

```
$("field").blur(function(){
```

should be

```
$(field).blur(function(){
```

And I'm not sure where you're getting the variable `f_name` from.

Answer (score 0):

```
textValidate("#f_name");
textValidate("#l_name");
```

also you sure you need the #?

Answer (score 0):

i thibk there is a type here:

```
    if (f_name.value.length > 1 && f_name.value.match(alphaExp)) {
        document.getElementById(field+"_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
    }
```

should be

```
    if (field.value.length > 1 && field.value.match(alphaExp)) {
        document.getElementById(field+"_mark").innerHTML = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
    }
```

one here:

```
    $("field").blur(function(){
```

should be

```
       $(field).blur(function(){
```

and

```
textValidate(#f_name);
textValidate(#l_name);
```

should be

```
textValidate('#f_name');
textValidate('#l_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CSS selectors in `document.getElementById(id)`

Use

```
$(field + "_mark").html("<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>");
```

instead.

Also your `textValidate` function must take a string:

```
textValidate("#f_name");
textValidate("#l_name");
```

Also instead of `f_name.value` you probably mean (if you are not developing for IE only..)

> $("#f_name").val()

or

> $(field).val()

, not sure.

Finally, your `<input>` elements are missing their end tags `</input>`.

Answer (score 0):

Among the other answers, you're using a jQuery selector which expects `#myId`, and getElementById which expects `myId`.  Prepending the pound sign will not return the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```
$.fn.textValidate = function() {
    this.blur(function() {
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\sàèìòùáéíóúäëïöüñãõåæøâêîôû-]+$/;
        var mark = $(this).next('span');

        if ($(this).val().match(alphaExp))
            mark.html("<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>");
        else
           mark.html("<img src='images/icons/cross.png' class='mark'>");
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#f_name').textValidate();
    $('#l_name').textValidate();
});
```

However, the structure of your HTML is flawed here. A much better way of writing everything can be see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/DPj28/).

---

#### HTML

```
<label>First name
    <input type="text" id="f_name" />
    <img class="mark" />
</label>
<label>Last name
    <input type="text" id="l_name" />
    <img class="mark" />
</label>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#f_name, #l_name').blur(function() {
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\sàèìòùáéíóúäëïöüñãõåæøâêîôû-]+$/;
        var mark = $(this).next('.mark');

        if ($(this).val().match(alphaExp))
            mark.attr('src', 'images/icons/tick.png');
        else 
            mark.attr('src', 'images/icons/cross.png');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery blur function is invoked using a jQuery Object.  This means that your function will fail if you call it using

```
textValidate(#f_name);
```

f_name is neither a string nor a jQuery object.  To solve your problem, I understand you are trying to make your function as generic as possible so that it can be applied to other fields.  Try this:

```
function textValidate(field) {
    $(field).blur(function(){
        var value = $(field).val();
        var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\sàèìòùáéíóúäëïöüñãõåæøâêîôû-]+$/;
        if (value.length > 1 && value.match(alphaExp)) {
            $(field+"_mark").html = "<img src='images/icons/tick.png' class='mark'>";
        }
        else {
            $(field+"_mark").html = "<img src='images/icons/cross.png' class='mark'>";
        }
    });
}
```

Now all you have to do to call this function is to pass the css selector as the argument:

```
textValidate("#f_name");
```

Take note that the argument is a string.  That's it.

Comment: I added an extra line in the blur function to save the value of the field as a variable.  I also modified your javascript to using jQuery selectors and functions.